# Symfony 1.4 order a widgets data

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms, doctrine-1.2

I have a sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceMany widget, I was wondering if there was a way to order the data inside it in ascending order

```
  'locations_list'  => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceMany(array('model' => 'Location')),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set ordering on *sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceMany* (and *sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice* too) you should provide a `order_by` option. Like this:

```
// ...
'locations_list' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceMany(array(
    'model'    => 'Location',
    'order_by' => array('Name', 'asc'), // <--- replace 'Name' with your column name in camel-case format
)),
// ...
```

---

When I need to get a quick reference on widget supported options, I always go to it's source. Usually they have a nice documentation right in PHP comments. Check this link to sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice source:

https://github.com/nationalfield/symfony/blob/a2d4442dfeb26355e89360f6e725c1f19c3a1ee0/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice.class.php#L33

Comment: Worth noting that it also accepts a doctrine query if further filtering is needed. http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en/A-Widgets#chapter_a_sub_choice_bound_to_a_doctrine_model